# been to & gone to: a general rule for specific cases

Tags: word-choice, present-perfect, past-participles, been-vs-gone

I understand *been to* is used for a complete visit and *gone to* refers to a trip taking place now or the person being there. My question is about the times where it's gets a bit shady. Based on what I see and hear I began to figure out a rule and I need to check it with an English native speaker: *we **can** use have you **gone to** a place instead of **been to** if the journey to that place is short and we're talking about a recent experience. If we focus on a long trip to a place and we focus on a life experience, we use been to.*

Talking to a tourist visiting Paris at the hotel:

> Have you gone to/been to the top of the Eiffel tower yet? [Both are possible]

Talking to a friend back home in Russia:

> Have you ever been to Paris? [Only been to is possible]

Does the rule make sense, or is there a point here I've failed noticing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR **GO to** refers to the journey there; **BE to** refers to the experience of being there, having intentionally gone there.

To **be** *to* a place is to travel there (by foot, by horse, by vehicle, etc). In the broadest sense, you take *deliberate* steps to get there. The place is your destination.

If you had been kidnapped, say, and taken to Boston,  a city you'd never set foot in before, you would not say "I've been to Boston" except facetiously, as you did not take deliberate steps yourself to get there. You cannot say that you have experienced Boston, having intentionally gone there.

Although it is not used much nowadays, you can say:

> I [am to](https://books.google.com/books?id=TsQwV_WZ-4EC&pg=PT61&lpg=PT61&dq=%22I%20am%20to%20London%22&source=bl&ots=ljfX2u98er&sig=vCV9W5I0baFjrKS2U6zyRlGEHSg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjk_ZyiucffAhXudN8KHXQHBxoQ6AEwA3oECBEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22I%20am%20to%20London%22&f=false) London.

which means "I am going to London" or "London is my destination".

When you want to say that you  made a trip to London in the past:

> I was to London  on a business trip ten years ago.

When you want to say  that you count London among the places you've visited, or that you recently were there:

> I have been to London.

Excluding the sense "to attend" (as, for example, a school, or musical instrument lessons) to **go** to a place is to travel to it.

> I go to London every two weeks on business.
>
> Ten years ago I went to London every two weeks on business.
>
> I have gone to London on business.

Brevity of visit and recency of visit (your "rule") are not essential to the meaning of **go**:

> There used to be a family with three sets of twins living in this house. Do they still live here in town?
>   --Oh, no. They've long since gone to London.

P.S. With respect to summits, like the Eiffel Tower, which you ask about, or the peak of Mount Everest, we can inquire whether someone has made their way to the top:

> Have you gone up?

or has been present there (has had the experience of being) up at the top:

> Have you been up?

Someone who had parachuted down to the peak of Mount Everest might say:

> I've been up, but I haven't gone up.

Comment: +1 Thank you I've learned many new things in your answer including what people actually say in modern English. Though I'm not sure if I got it right. You mean **_gone to_ and _been to_ are changeable when they refer to heights** and they're not when you refer to visits? Please note my question was about visiting a place plus coming back or not being back.

Comment: Your question was about a specious "rule" that involved "short trips" versus "long trips". My answer does not attempt to make a rule about heights; heights are used only incidentally as an example.  The relevant distinction between **go to** and **be to** is that the former entails deliberate steps to reach the destination, and the latter entails presence at and experience of a place.

Comment: *I went to the exhibit but couldn't get in the door, they had so many visitors. So I guess you could say that I've gone to it but I haven't been to it.*

Comment: So, there's no practical difference between _Have you gone to Paris/the top of the Eiffel Tower?_ and _Have you been to Paris/the top of the Eiffel Tower?_ Except for what you just said. Am I right? Sorry just checking. :-)

Comment: The difference is between volitional travel to a destination (*go to*) on the one hand, and on the other hand, presence in and first-hand experience of a place (*be to*).

Comment: If I ask you "Have you ever *gone* to the top of X monument?" and you say Yes, I might ask you if you took the stairs or the elevator.  If I ask you if you have *been* to the top of X monument, and you say yes, I might ask you what you liked most about the view from that height.

Comment: Have you ever gone to Paris? asking if the person has ever had a trip like they wanted to, to Paris no matter they actually made it or not and Have you ever been to Paris? asking if the person has the experience of any sort in that place. Did I get it right? :-) [preparing to celebrate lol]

Comment: *Have you ever gone to Paris?* You're asking the person if they've ever made a trip to Paris. It  is something you might ask a young airline pilot: has he ever had occasion to fly to Paris on one of his routes. If you wanted to know if someone has ever enjoyed what Paris has to offer, you'd ask *Have you ever been to Paris?*

Comment: Oh the action of going itself like the movement thing when you go somewhere. I'm beginning to understand now. Thanks I think I got it. :-)

Comment: Yes, "volitional travel to a destination".

Comment: Obviously we cannot wish ourselves to a place. We have to travel in order to go there and we must have traveled to a distant place to say we have been there (if it was not our home).  But **go** refers to the journey there and **be** refers to the experience once there.

Comment: Thiusa answer is wrong in an important detail: _be to_ (in this sense **does not exist**. The idiom is only _been to_. In particular _I was to London on a business trip ten years ago_. is not grammatical, in any English I am familiar with.

Comment: @ColinFine:  My local mid-Atlantic dialect has pockets influenced by Irish-English speakers and I've heard it used around here, mainly by older speakers without much education. Here's something local from 1890: "**i was to town** on the 22 of feb[r]uary and not [th]inking of Washington birthday til i got to town and seen [sic] the banks and stores all closed" and here's an attestation from an early 20th century diary of a farmer in Canada: "Sat. May 25 Fine weather, good market especially tomato plants, I sowed beans and peas at Erdmans. afternoon - **was to town evenings** with the asparagus"

Comment: And here's a contemporary attestation of "I was to {place/destination}" from Texas: "And then, just yesterday, **I was to Town East Mall** — and, like, so many people were stopping me! It was insane."

Answer (score 1):

**Been to** means visit as a form of go and come.

Elmer is travelling around Europe. He's been to 3 countries so far. He's been to France, he's been to Germany and now he's here with me in Manchester. It's the first time he's been to England.

**Gone to** with I, you, and we used to be difficult, but now we all have mobile phones we can call and ask "Where have you gone? I can't find you anywhere!" Gone to really means *not here.* Have you gone to the top of the Eiffel tower? No. I'm here, talking to you..

Comment: Well, that's wierd because I saw this in a Top Notch coursebook. In the lesson about talking about travel experiences, _Have you gone to the top of the Harbour Center Tower?_ occurrs as a question in an on-the-street interview with a tourist in Canada. Actually this made me reconsider what I knew about _been to_ and _gone to_ and try to come up with a rule. Are you suggesting this question is a pointless one?

Comment: I would love to go over your book with you, but sadly.. Yeah, think about it. Gone to = not here. Even Murphy's English Grammar in Use won't tell you that Been to is a form of go or come ;-)

Comment: +1 Thank you Matt though you just sent me to square 1 :-)

Comment: Yuri. This is a video I made about been to / in. It also explains gone  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8T-n6ZAS-Ac